# Ubuntu USB installation

Tags: usb, system

Am trying to download Ubuntu onto USB drive as advised but every time I download & go to Browse, it never shows in Window to select. Am I missing something ?
The original problem I have is a corrupted file system on an external HDD with All my critical files on without a back up. 
I have been advised that using Ubuntu in this way might help me access and retrieve said files ?
Would appreciate any help very much thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you can still run Windows I'd go against running Ubuntu just for *that*. Instead I'd recommend you to use PhotoRec directly on Windows.

- Go to the [PhotoRec/TestDisk download page](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download)
- Download the latest Windows (not Windows 64-bit) beta build
- Extract the downloaded archive
- Run the file `qphotorec_win.exe` inside of the extracted folder as administrator
- In the dialog:

  - Select the disk and partition you'd like to recover
  - Select "FAT/NTFS/HFS+/RaiserFS/..." as "File system type
  - Select "Whole: Extract files from whole partition"
  - Use a new directory as output directory on some other HDD that has as much free space as you can afford (3x the size of the source volume is the recommended value)
  - Start analyzing by pressing the "Search" button

Of course you should check out Ubuntu anyways! :-P

Comment: Thank you so much for that, I will look into that tmrw / asap.

Comment: I havent had chance to get stuck into that today but will do asap.  The source disk is 1tb HDD so a 3 x capacity receiving disk is never going to happen unfortunately. I have cloned the problem drive onto a 1tb Sata HDD so will work on that. the data is roughly 500-600gb I think from memory. All I can think of is trying to copy some data back to laptop HDD (500gb but with only 370 spare) and take it bit by bit but this is all very new to me. I think the reason the Installer wasnt showing may be because I use Opera, so will change to I.E. & see. thanks